# Is there a reason for this redundancy in Angular with ngModel in "template-driven approach"?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, ngmodel

Consider the following mark-up:

```
<input id="name" required minlength="4">
```

Now, to bring this input field under Angular's control (that is, have Angular create a control object and associate it with said input field), we add the following directives:

```
<input id="name" required minlength="4"
      ngModel name="name" #name="ngModel" >
```

This, of course, enables us to have a reference to the field/control object which could be used for, say, displaying a validation `div`.

```
<div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)"
     class="alert alert-danger">
```

I'm just wondering if there's a reason the Angular developer's wouldn't let us use the value of the `name` attribute-- which is, of course, required when using ngModel on the field -- to refer to the control. Why the need for the seeming redundant/verbose assignment of ngModel to a template variable `#name="ngModel"`?

Comment: `<input name="someName" [(ngModel)]="myPropertyName">` would be enough to make it work, wouldn't it.

Comment: It wouldn't work with nested ngModels (using [NgModelGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModelGroup)).

Comment: I don't see that in the question though. It would be indeed redundant to add this just because you might want to change it into a group sometime.

Comment: @lexith i changed the question. I didn't mean to use ngModel as a binding to a property of the component, but rather to have angular create an on-the-fly formControl object.

Comment: But I think @JBNizet has answered the question. Thanks.